# AWS ELB erroring out 400 Bad request for more than 35 requests at a time when session stickiness is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, wkhtmltopdf, amazon-elb

We are using session stickiness in `AWS ELB` to maintain session for our application on multiple instances. We are using wkhtmltopdf tool to send requests to this ELB endpoint for generating header and footer for PDF generation from HTML. We are not able to generate header and footer for PDFs which are more than 17 pages. After deep investigation it is found that ELB gives **400 Bad request** error after 35 requests(18 headers and 17 footers) [Verified this error in access_logs]. This happens even when instance count is one. However, after disabling session stickiness(one instance), able to generate proper PDFs for even more than 17 pages. Not able to understand this weird behaviour of `AWS ELB`.

Has anyone faced similar issues with Sticky session enabled in `AWS ELB`.

Comment: are you sending the session cookies with your requests?

Comment: Calling it "access_logs" implies that the error is in the web server logs... which tends to point the finger at the instance rather than the balancer.  Can you capture the response headers and body from the 400 response?

Comment: @at0mzk, we are sending both application cookie and AWSELB cookie. Header/Footer are getting generated for 1st 17 pages.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  Am not getting this error when stickiness is disabled.  So I doubt if this could be a bug in AWS ELB stickiness.

Comment: you remember how you solved it @OnkaarSingh?